# bulk insert into temp table from a text file

Tags: sql-server-2008

is there a way to bulk insert a text file content into a SQL temp table?

I want to insert each row in a text file into separate rows in the SQL Temp Table. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SQL Server `BULK INSERT` command. Though it depends on data format in file but at a simplest example; if your file has data like below and file name is `data.txt`

```
Kelly, Reynold, kelly@reynold.com
```

Then the command should look like

```
BULK INSERT temp_table FROM 'D:\data.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',');
```

Comment: The Data is unstructured. I want to store each row of the text file into a separate row in the Temp Table.

Comment: Yes, rows will be stored separately. my answer gives you a good head start. go through MSDN document on bulk insert once and you will get it through.

Comment: Question asked about 'temp table'